# Qtip2 ToolTip Not Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, qtip2

I have this code running -

```
 $(".imgClass").each( (elem,value)->
      imgSrc = $(value).attr("src")
      $(value).qtip({
        content: "<img src=" + imgSrc + ">"
        position:{
            corner:{
              target:'leftTop',
              tooltip:'bottomRight'
            }

        }


        })
      )
```

The img shows up fine, but the tooltip is always positioned at the bottom right of the target, as oppposed to leftTop.

I think it probably is a syntax error - can anyone help? (Also, this is written in coffeescript, hence no ;s, but I've kept the parantheses because I'm still unclear on coffee)

Thanks

Comment: Are you preloading your images?

Answer (score 6):

qTip2 doesn't use positioning like that any more. It uses the `my` and `at` params instead.

```
position: {
    my: 'top left',
    at: 'bottom right'
}
```

(The actual values you'll need to play with, but that's the general syntax).

[qTip2 Positioning Documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/position/)